# What was the significance in Laura tipping over the cross in Logan?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In *Logan*, in the final scene, Laura takes the cross on Logan's grave and tips it over. Why did she do that?

Here's what I'm talking about:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a symbol of X-Men. The very same logo X-Men movies are using.

[image]

It's not stated in the movie why she did that. In my opinion, she feels that it will link to Charles Xavier and the X-Men he was a part of. Logan has sacrificed his life to save her and her friends, a group of young mutants. She was honoring the man for what he was, what he did.

This [Looper article](https://www.looper.com/45992/ending-logan-explained/) sheds some light on this (emphasis mine),

> Laura picks up the little wooden cross that marked Logan's grave and tilts it on its side, making an X. That's a pretty obvious nod to, well, the X-Men. But it's also a pretty beautiful, quiet statement about the kind of guy Wolverine was throughout all these movies. **The cross at a gravesite is meant to reflect a person's faith in God, in something higher than them. Obviously Logan wasn't much of a Christian—but he was an X-Man, and he spent his life fighting for the betterment of mutantkind and the ideals of Charles Xavier.** The fact that he devoted the final years of his life to taking care of Xavier shows that, despite his insistence that he didn't care about much, he believed in Xavier and his dream of peace and prosperity more than he might have admitted.

Comment: Saying that it's the logo in the movies makes it seem like an obscure reference. Most fans would know they wear an X icon on their costumes, like superman's S.